# Follow the end Url in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to follow a Url which is in a RSS to find the end URL!
so for example I have this URL "http://coder.io/~a27983554a" and the result of following this will be "http://ferd.ca/code-janitor-nobody-s-dream-everyone-s-job-and-how-erlang-can-help.html"

The end URL is saved in the header of the first URL, but the problem is I need to send a request to that URL to get response containing the end result for me!

I'm using this command

> {ok, {{Version, 200, ReasonPhrase}, Headers, Body}} = httpc:request("http://coder.io/~a27983554a")

but this just give me the Headers of the file but the response from the site containing my result

Please help me
I'm new in Erlang and it will be perfect if you can provide simple line of code for example

Thanks in advance

Comment: The "end result" (in HTML format) is already bound to your "Body" variable. Print it using `io:format("~s", [Body]).` to verify that.

Comment: The Body does not contain the redirect link, is there a way to get the response header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable `autoredirect` when performing the request:

```
Method = get,
Url = "http://coder.io/~a27983554a",
HTTPOptions = [{autoredirect, false}],
{ok, {{_Version, 302, _StatusMsg}, Headers, Body}} =
    httpc:request(Method, {Url, []}, HTTPOptions, []),
Location = proplists:get_value("location", Headers).
```

Comment: Thanks Man that helps alot! Is there anywhere that we can see the different options available? because I was reading the official doc and there is not much to it in details. and thanks again

Comment: HTTP Options are documented at: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-5