# Erlang Get the final redirected URL

Tags: get, erlang, redirect, httpc

As given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671352/follow-the-end-url-in-erlang) question, I used below method for finding the final redirected URL as

```
URL="http://mail.google.com",
HTTPOpts = [{autoredirect, false}],
perform_request(URL) ->
case httpc:request(get, {URL, [{"User-Agent", "Mozilla"}]}, HTTPOpts, []) of
   {ok, {{_, Code, _}, Headers, Body}}  when Code == 200  ->

       %%code_to_process_the_URL%%

   {ok, {{_, Code, _}, Headers, _}}  when Code < 310 , Code >= 300 ->

     NewURL=proplists:get_value("location", Headers),
     perform_request(NewURL)
     end
```

This works fine for other URLs but it faces issues with `URL = https://mail.google.com` as its first location header is `location = /mail/` which is not a valid URL and I get a empty page.

I also generated output using `GET` command to verify this on terminal.

output:

```
mandeep@mandeep-Inspiron-5447:~$ GET -S -d -e http://mail.google.com
GET http://mail.google.com
301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:56:14 GMT
Accept-Ranges: none
Location: /mail/
Server: GSE
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:56:14 GMT
Client-Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:55:30 GMT
Client-Peer: 216.58.197.69:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Title: Moved Permanently
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

GET http://mail.google.com/mail/
302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:56:15 GMT
Accept-Ranges: none
Location: https://mail.google.com/mail/
Server: GSE
Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:56:15 GMT
Client-Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:55:30 GMT
Client-Peer: 172.217.26.165:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Title: Moved Temporarily
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

GET https://mail.google.com/mail/
302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:56:21 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: none
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1
Server: GSE
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"
Client-Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:55:36 GMT
Client-Peer: 216.58.197.69:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet
Authority G2
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google        Inc/CN=mail.google.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
Title: Moved Temporarily
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

GET https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1
200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:56:22 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: GSE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Mon, 01-Jan-1990 00:00:00 GMT
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34"
Client-Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 11:55:38 GMT
Client-Peer: 172.217.26.173:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet     Authority G2
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google    Inc/CN=accounts.google.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Link: <https://www.google.com/gmail/>; rel="canonical"
Set-Cookie:   GAPS=1:uiUyF1S0WckgUUlRhZmrUeuRVCgCiA:9vKBlzT8ecd7l7Ob;Path=/;Expires=Thu,    21-Feb-2019 11:56:22 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly;Priority=HIGH
Set-Cookie: GALX=mfArYRFLcco;Path=/;Secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=10893354; includeSubDomains
Title: Gmail
X-Auto-Login:realm=com.google&args=service%3Dmail%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com%252Fmail%252F
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Meta-Charset: utf-8
X-Meta-Description: Gmail is email that's intuitive, efficient, and
useful. 15 GB of storage, less spam, and mobile access.
X-Meta-Google-Site-Verification: LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs
X-Meta-Viewport: width=300, initial-scale=1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

How this issue can be resolved?

Comment: What command line command is that?  Link?

Answer (score 1):

You can not change what's been returned to you, so you will have to deal with it.

Whenever you get an absolute URL in `NewURL` (for instance if it has http on it) you can redirect. Otherwise, if you get a relative URL, compose a ´NewURL2´ with the URL used for the initial request `URL` + the location in `NewURL`. An implementation option might be this:

```
case proplists:get_value("location", Headers) of
  NewURLAbsolute = [$h, $t, $t, $p, _Rest] ->
                   perform_request(NewURLAbsolute);
  NewURLRelative -> perform_request(URL ++ NewURLRelative)
end
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can get the final URL after all redirections without using recursive loop manually, like it is done by `GET` or any BIF in erlang ?

Comment: There might be more URLs like `http://mail.google.com`, are you sure that the solution will work for all such URLs

Comment: The code I posted only ensures that if http is present in the location, you can use it as it is (it's an absolute URL). Otherwise, You need to append it to the original URL because it's relative. I understood your problem was with the ´/mail/´ location not being a valid URL on its own.